# Consuming Rest Web Service with Bottle (JQuery and JSON)

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, rest, bottle

I want to consume this rest web service that returns a JSON response:

**web_service.py**

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/example')
def example():
    return {"result_1" : 3, "result_2" : 5}

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

My JavaScript file is something like this:

**java_s.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET"
        url: "http://localhost:8080/example",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(resp){
            $('.result_1').append(resp.result_1)
            $('.result_2').append(resp.result_2)
        }
    })
});
```

And my html file where I want to cosume the web service is:

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <title>example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="java_s.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p class="result_1">result 1: </p>
        <p class="result_2">result 2: </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

However, when I open the index file the results aren't shown. Can you give me some suggestion to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: What does 'http://localhost:8080/example' return?

Comment: It returns: {"result_1" : 3, "result_2" : 5} and I wanted to show that result in the html file. I added the statement: response.content_type = "application/json" in the web service but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a python dict object, not a json string. You can encode the string manually or use, for example, the json library to actually output json.

Add `import json` to the beginning of your file and then change to `return json.dumps({"result_1" : 3, "result_2" : 5})` to return an actual json string created from your python dict object.